# How do I animate bottom AND opacity attribute in GSAP and ScrollMagic?

Tags: javascript, css, gsap, scrollmagic

With the following code I am able to stagger animate the position and fade the text in. But what I'd like to accomplish is to move, fade in, **and then** fade all copy back to 0 by end of scroll. So moving is working fine. I  just want the same `<p>` tags to fade in then back out by end of scroll.

```
// init controller to hold all commands/animations
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({ addIndicators: true });

const tween1 = TweenMax
  .staggerTo('#parallax p', 1, {
    bottom: $('#parallax').height(),
    opacity: 1,
  }, 0.06);

// All commands/animations live in a scene
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  // Element to watch
  triggerElement: '#parallax',
  // Point at which animation starts, default is center of screen
  triggerHook: 0, // 1 onEnter, .5 onCenter (Defualt), 0 onLeave
})
.setPin('#parallax')
.setTween(tween1)
.duration('100%') // Percentage of full screen or hard-wired number of pixels
.addIndicators({ name: 'FADES' }) // Indicators marked on screen
.addTo(controller); // Add this scene to controller
```

Side question: If the animation is keyed to scroll through ScrollMagic, what is the `1` for in the following line: `.staggerTo('#parallax p', 1, {`?

Edit: More appropriate [CodePen added](https://codepen.io/LayneSmith/pen/yXEOxq)

Comment: can you create a codepen demo for us to debug. Thanks

Comment: you can try adding another tween to fade them out and trigger them on scroll out.

Comment: SIDE ANSWER: 1 is the duration of each animation. 0.06 is the time for the next animation to start.

Comment: Thanks! CodePen added to original post. https://codepen.io/LayneSmith/pen/yXEOxq

Comment: codepen looks perfect. what is your intent? what do you want is not clear. Can you please try to explain it further.

Comment: let me clarify: Should the text fade out while it is still in view??

Comment: Yes, right now the type fades in as it scrolls off the page. I would like it to fade in as it scroll up and then fade out towards the top of the screen and before it leaves the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something more like this? https://codepen.io/motionimaging/pen/155bf1892710fb95dcc81ddb7201adb0/

```
// init controller to hold all commands/animations
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({ addIndicators: true });

var timeline = new TimelineMax();
var tween1 = TweenMax.staggerFromTo("#two p", 1, {bottom: 0},{bottom: $('#two').height()}, 0.1);

var tween2a = TweenMax.staggerTo("#two p", 0.5,{ opacity: 1 }, 0.1);

var tween2b = TweenMax.staggerTo("#two p", 0.35,{ opacity: 0 }, 0.1);

timeline.add(tween1, 0)
    .add(tween2a, 0)
    .add(tween2b, 0.5);

new ScrollMagic.Scene({
   triggerElement: "#two",
  triggerHook: 0,
})
.setTween(timeline)
.setPin("#two")
.duration("200%") 
.addIndicators({ name: "FADES" })
.addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfect so I accepted the answer. Thank you. I added a few more elements and adjusted some settings but now the when scrolling back up the type opacity doesn't fade back out giving the appearance of the text stacking up. Clearly I'm not understanding, I'm not sure the disconnect between what worked (yours) and my changes. https://codepen.io/LayneSmith/pen/yXEOxq

Comment: You need to make sure Tween2b starts after Tween 2a. So if the duration of Tween2a is 0.75 (as yours is) the start time of Tween 2b must be 0.75 (`.add(tween2b, 0.75)`)